# Hibernate mapping: creating FK relation in existing db for join operations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an existing db that I cannot alter. There are two tables, one (A) with a PK and one (B) with a FK pointing to the PK of the first. The respective columns are named (A).page_id and (B).cl_from. 
In Hibernate mapping i can set an id for the first, mapping the PK. I can also set a bag for the one-to-many relationship.
For the second, I don't need an id, but a many-to-one relationship. How can you set a many-to-one relationship without an id? I don't want to insert an id to the class..
I've tried to set a composite key but had no luck..

```
// The PK class
<class name="Words" table="PAGE">
  <id name="id" column="PAGE_ID" />
  <property name="text" column="PAGE_TITLE" />  
  <bag cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="wordPages">
     <key column="PAGE_ID"/>
     <one-to-many class="CategoryItems"/>
  </bag>
</class>

// The FK class
<class name="CategoryItems" table="CATEGORYLINKS" >
  <composite-id> 
    <key-many-to-one name="id" column="CL_FROM" />
  </composite-id>
  <property name="text" column="CL_TO" />
</class>
```

And my classes:

```
 public class Words {

 private Long id;
 private String text;
 private ArrayList wordPages;
// getters - setters

public class CategoryItems implements Serializable  {

/**
 * 
 */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Long id;
  private String text;

//getters-setters
```

The latest error i get is: `An association from the table CATEGORYLINKS refers to an unmapped class: java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should help with the following code:

```
public class CategoryItems implements Serializable  
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Words id;
  private String text;

  //getters-setters
}
```

Comment: It resolved the current error but now it's `Path expected for join! [from Words as W inner join CategoryItems as I where I.text = 'myText']`. This also occurred before but I haven't managed to solve with numerous ways..